# What is a MIDI soundbank?

Tags: java, midi, javasound, pcm

I am a neophyte at MIDI.  Does a MIDI soundbank contains "instructions" [sic] for a MIDI synthesizer to turn into PCM audio?

I have numerous pieces of variable-duration audio (currently in PCM and thus my ask) that I would like to sequence (if you will) and provide instructions to play (and mix them) based upon a server-generated timeline.  MIDI logically seems to be the answer, though I am a little fuzzy on **what exactly is a soundbank** and if it is indeed just a bank of PCM sounds?

---

Update: I am initially looking at this from Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A soundbank is a collection of digital recordings each intended to be used as a digital musical instrument.  I think what you are looking for is a MIDI sequencer that will allow you to specify the soundbank.

You haven't mentioned your development platform, which is a key (no pun intended) piece of needed information.  Do you already have a MIDI sequencer available in a library?

Comment: Correct it is Java, and updated in the question.  I know there are some limitations in the format of the commercial soundbank with the java sound api (or rather its default impl).